# How to find if this huge vector is in the column space of this huge matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, proof-verification, vectors

I newbie to linear algebra, so I hope you are patient with me.

I have to say if a vector $\vec{u} = \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{matrix} \right]$ is in the **column space** of a matrix $A = \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1&0&0&-1&0&1&1 \\ 0&1&0&0&-1&0&1 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&-1&0&1&0&1 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&1&0&1&-1\end{matrix} \right]$.

My intuition is to say no, because, if I am not wrong, what we need to find is a vector $\vec{v}$ such that $$A\vec{v} = \vec{u}$$

But there's no vector such that multiplied by a row of all $0$s (the matrix row before its last one), which will give $1$, the component before the last of $\vec{u}$.

Am I right or what? Should I need to find the $RREF$ anyway?

Comment: You are right. You don't need to

Comment: Technically you saw that $(Av)_6 = 0$ for any $v\in\mathbb R^7$ but $u_6 = 1$ so $(Av)_6 \ne u_6$ for any $v$, so $Av \ne u$ for any $v$. QED.

Comment: Just project and subtract the projections one by one. If you get the 0 vector at any point of that process then yes, it is in the space.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right [...] ?

Yes.               $  $

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is almost right. 
Let $V$ denote the column space of matrix $A$, you need to find a combination of vectors $v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n} \in V$, that gives $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {\alpha_i v_{i}} = v$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$.
If you can find a combination like so, then $v\in V$

Comment: Why do you talk about a linear combination of vectors in the column space? Isn't it simpler to just talk about a linear combination of the columns themselves? And the linear combinations of the columns really are $A\vec{v}$ for all possible $\vec v$, so as far as I can tell Rinzler is exactly correct.

Comment: @OscarCunningham Heck, why not just talk about linear combinations of the *numbers* that specify the columns?

Comment: When you are looking at a vector and trying to prove it's in the column space, you have to write it as a linear combination of the base of it. That is the easiest way in my opinion.